# Proportions by group with srvyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

Hi, I have a data frame with a weight column like the example:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~edu, ~q_d1, ~q_d2_1, ~weight,
   1L,   1L,    1L,      0L,    1740,
   2L,   1L,    1L,      0L,    1428,
   3L,   2L,    1L,      2L,     496,
   4L,   2L,    1L,      2L,     550,
   5L,   3L,    1L,      1L,    1762,
   6L,   4L,    1L,      0L,    1004,
   7L,   5L,    1L,      0L,     522,
   8L,   3L,    2L,      0L,    1099,
   9L,   4L,    2L,      2L,    1295
  )
```

I use srvyr package to calculate summary statistics with group. My script:

```
sv_design_test <- df %>%
  srvyr::as_survey_design(weights = weight)

sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone" ,
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone" ,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(smartphone) %>% 
  summarize(proportion = srvyr::survey_mean(),
            total = srvyr::survey_total(),
            total_unweighted = srvyr::unweighted(n())) %>% 
  select(-proportion_se, -total_se )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  smartphone    proportion total total_unweighted
  <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>            <int>
1 No Internet        0.242  2394                2
2 No smartphone      0.474  4694                4
3 smartphone         0.284  2808                3
```

but when I add education (edu) to group_by I got an error:

```
sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone" ,
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone" ,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(edu, smartphone) %>% 
  summarize(proportion = srvyr::survey_mean(),
            total = srvyr::survey_total(),
            total_unweighted = srvyr::unweighted(n())) %>% 
  select(-proportion_se, -total_se )
```

The error message is:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Comment: Read back over that error and look at your data. The error says the groups need to be factors with 2+ levels. Your `edu` is numeric. Before creating the survey design, convert `edu` to a factor.

Comment: Thnaks @camille , your comment is valid but I got the same error after conversion!

Comment: Yes, `smartphone` also needs to be a factor

Comment: I got this Error in cbind_all(x) : Argument 3 must be length 15, not 7, I tried to convert 'smartphone' before group_by

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Problem

Your error message (the one about contrasts) says that you need to use factors as your grouping variables. In your original data frame, `edu` is numeric, so you can convert it to a factor before you create the survey design.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(srvyr)

# ...

sv_design_test <- df %>%
  mutate(edu = as.factor(edu)) %>%
  srvyr::as_survey_design(weights = weight)
```

Then after you create `smartphone`, convert that to a factor as well:

```r
sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone" ,
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone" ,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(smartphone = as.factor(smartphone))
```

In your second error message (the one about lengths), it's because you have functions in your `summarise` that return different numbers of rows. You can verify that by calling those functions separately (the error message says it's argument 3, meaning `n = unweighted(n())`, where the issue is).

This returns 15 rows:

```r
sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone",
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(smartphone = as.factor(smartphone)) %>%
  group_by(edu, smartphone) %>% 
  summarise(prop = survey_mean(), 
            total = survey_total())
#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#>    edu   smartphone     prop prop_se total total_se
#>    <fct> <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 1     No Internet   0       0         0       0 
#>  2 1     No smartphone 1       0      3168    2108.
#>  3 1     smartphone    0       0         0       0 
#>  4 2     No Internet   0       0         0       0 
#>  5 2     No smartphone 0       0         0       0 
#>  6 2     smartphone    1       0      1046     693.
#>  7 3     No Internet   0.384   0.355  1099    1099.
#>  8 3     No smartphone 0       0         0       0 
#>  9 3     smartphone    0.616   0.355  1762    1762.
#> 10 4     No Internet   0.563   0.369  1295    1295.
#> 11 4     No smartphone 0.437   0.369  1004    1004 
#> 12 4     smartphone    0       0         0       0 
#> 13 5     No Internet   0       0         0       0 
#> 14 5     No smartphone 1       0       522     522 
#> 15 5     smartphone    0       0         0       0
```

While this returns only 7, because there are only 7 combinations of `edu` and `smartphone` that appear, and therefore only 7 that get counted.

```r
sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone",
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(smartphone = as.factor(smartphone)) %>%
  group_by(edu, smartphone) %>%
  summarise(n = unweighted(n()))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   edu   smartphone        n
#>   <fct> <fct>         <int>
#> 1 1     No smartphone     2
#> 2 2     smartphone        2
#> 3 3     No Internet       1
#> 4 3     smartphone        1
#> 5 4     No Internet       1
#> 6 4     No smartphone     1
#> 7 5     No smartphone     1
```

### Solution 1: Using `.drop = FALSE` within `group_by()`

You can force `summarize()` to produce results even for combinations of factor levels that don't appear in the data by using the `.drop` argument of the `group_by()` function.

```r
sv_design_test %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
        q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
        q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone",
        q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone",
        TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
      mutate(smartphone = as.factor(smartphone)) %>%
      group_by(edu, smartphone,
               .drop = FALSE) %>%
      summarize(prop= srvyr::survey_mean(),
                total = srvyr::survey_total(),
                total_unweighted = srvyr::unweighted(n()))

#> # A tibble: 15 x 7
#>    edu   smartphone     prop prop_se total total_se total_unweighted
#>    <fct> <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1     No Internet   0       0         0       0      0
#>  2 1     No smartphone 1       0      3168    2108.     2
#>  3 1     smartphone    0       0         0       0      0
#>  4 2     No Internet   0       0         0       0      0
#>  5 2     No smartphone 0       0         0       0      0
#>  6 2     smartphone    1       0      1046     693.     2
#>  7 3     No Internet   0.384   0.355  1099    1099.     1
#>  8 3     No smartphone 0       0         0       0      0
#>  9 3     smartphone    0.616   0.355  1762    1762.     1
#> 10 4     No Internet   0.563   0.369  1295    1295.     1
#> 11 4     No smartphone 0.437   0.369  1004    1004      1
#> 12 4     smartphone    0       0         0       0      0
#> 13 5     No Internet   0       0         0       0      0
#> 14 5     No smartphone 1       0       522     522      1
#> 15 5     smartphone    0       0         0       0      0
```

### Solution 2: Joining

You could make 2 different summarized data frames and then join them.

I'm adding a call to `complete` after `n()` to fill in missing levels. Making two data frames and joining them gets the following:

```r
props <- sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone",
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(smartphone = as.factor(smartphone)) %>%
  group_by(edu, smartphone) %>% 
  summarise(prop = survey_mean(), 
            total = survey_total())

counts <- sv_design_test %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone",
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  mutate(smartphone = as.factor(smartphone)) %>%
  group_by(edu, smartphone) %>%
  summarise(n = unweighted(n())) %>%
  complete(edu, smartphone, fill = list(n = 0))

left_join(props, counts, by = c("edu", "smartphone"))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 7
#>    edu   smartphone     prop prop_se total total_se     n
#>    <fct> <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1     No Internet   0       0         0       0      0
#>  2 1     No smartphone 1       0      3168    2108.     2
#>  3 1     smartphone    0       0         0       0      0
#>  4 2     No Internet   0       0         0       0      0
#>  5 2     No smartphone 0       0         0       0      0
#>  6 2     smartphone    1       0      1046     693.     2
#>  7 3     No Internet   0.384   0.355  1099    1099.     1
#>  8 3     No smartphone 0       0         0       0      0
#>  9 3     smartphone    0.616   0.355  1762    1762.     1
#> 10 4     No Internet   0.563   0.369  1295    1295.     1
#> 11 4     No smartphone 0.437   0.369  1004    1004      1
#> 12 4     smartphone    0       0         0       0      0
#> 13 5     No Internet   0       0         0       0      0
#> 14 5     No smartphone 1       0       522     522      1
#> 15 5     smartphone    0       0         0       0      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Now it is clear what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't actually require `srvyr`

```
df %>%
dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone" ,
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone" ,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
group_by(smartphone) %>%
summarise(total = sum(weight),
          total_unweighted = n()) %>%
mutate(proportion = prop.table(total))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  smartphone    total total_unweighted proportion
  <chr>         <dbl>            <int>      <dbl>
1 No Internet    2394                2      0.242
2 No smartphone  4694                4      0.474
3 smartphone     2808                3      0.284


df %>%
dplyr::mutate(smartphone = case_when(
    q_d1 == 2 ~ "No Internet",
    q_d2_1 > 0 ~ "smartphone" ,
    q_d2_1 == 0 ~ "No smartphone" ,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
group_by(edu, smartphone) %>%
summarise(total = sum(weight),
          total_unweighted = n()) %>%
mutate(proportion = prop.table(total))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   edu [5]
    edu smartphone    total total_unweighted proportion
  <int> <chr>         <dbl>            <int>      <dbl>
1     1 No smartphone  3168                2      1    
2     2 smartphone     1046                2      1    
3     3 No Internet    1099                1      0.384
4     3 smartphone     1762                1      0.616
5     4 No Internet    1295                1      0.563
6     4 No smartphone  1004                1      0.437
7     5 No smartphone   522                1      1
```

Comment: In this simple example that's true, but for a more complex survey design, they probably would need `srvyr` or its underlying `survey`